# WCF Service running on localhost (debug) but failing at deployment

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Service that works when i run it at localhost, using the WCF Test Client I can invoke it and get a result. I can also see it when I actually host it on the live server as it generates the methods on the test client and I can see the wsdl page when opened in Chrome.

But (because it always has a but) when I invoke it with WCF Test Client I get this error:

```
Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)   
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) 
Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)  at IRp3Services.CreateTransaction(NewTransaction model)   at Rp3ServicesClient.CreateTransaction(NewTransaction model)
```

I cant seem to understand why, I have tested it locally and works perfectly, here is the web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    </system.web>


<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ConsultasSoap" />
        <binding name="TransaccionesSoap" />
        <binding name="SeguridadSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://address/Rp3.Web.Credishop.Afiliados/consultas.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConsultasSoap"
        contract="RP3Consultas.ConsultasSoap" name="ConsultasSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://address/Rp3.Web.Credishop.Afiliados/transacciones.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransaccionesSoap"
        contract="RP3Transacciones.TransaccionesSoap" name="TransaccionesSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://address/Rp3.Web.Credishop.Afiliados/seguridad.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SeguridadSoap"
        contract="RP3Seguridad.SeguridadSoap" name="SeguridadSoap" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I am really at a loss here, I would love any input on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is this configuration owned by another application that is used to test the client of the deployed service? So your question is why the call with WcfTestClient failed? If it is, I suggest you modify the automatically generated configuration file after adding the published service address in WcfTestClient.

Comment: When I call the service using the WCFTestClient, I get the 3 methods I can use, if I am debugging the application, the process of using the create method works and I get the result, but if I use the live address I get to see the 3 methods too but when I invoke it I get that error, just on the live application.

Comment: Are the automatically generated configuration’s endpoints right?

Comment: I changed them when I put them here to not give the real address to the endpoints but they are correct on the web config file

Comment: Can you call the live service properly with the other application(such as the console application)?